# syncfusion datagrid in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, syncfusion

All,

I am trying to use `syncfusion data grid` in `xamarin forms` now.I have installed trial version as of now. I have created demo from this [link](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/syncfusionessentialstudio)

All is fine.I have added all references,no errors at all. but it doesn't shows the datagrid in output( i am using vs inbuilt emulator).it just shows the  blank screen like [image: this]

I couldn't find anything wrong what I have done in my code from above link.its really simple but still why  I am not getting output.please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should also add SfDataGridRenderer.Init(); method in required places.

Comment: isnt it is only fro ios and android.in article there is not mentioned we need to ad it in android also..and if yes then in which file do i add?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you load SfDataGrid directly as a child, the grid will be loaded. If you want to load SfDataGrid inside a ScrollView or a StackLayout, refer the below UG link to achieve it,

https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfdatagrid/getting-started#launching-the-sfdatagrid-inside-a-stacklayout

Also, you can refer our KB link below to achieve your requirement.

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/6169/how-to-load-sfdatagrid-in-a-stacklayout

If you need further assistance, please create a new support incident, using our direct trac system.

https://www.syncfusion.com/account/login

-Divakar

Comment: i m loading sfgrid ditectly.still its doesnt shows anything whts wrong with it?

Comment: Check whether you have set the ViewModel as BindingContext to the grid or assigned a collection in ViewModel as ItemsSource of the grid.

Comment: We have prepared a sample for your reference and you can download it from below link.                     http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/SampleDemo-2100734664

Comment: yes. i did it.exactly..and its showing grid with data in UWP.but not in android.m just stuck in this from long time

Comment: i had created suport incident also..but didnt get any response there

Comment: i had downloaded this demo from http://files2.syncfusion.com/Xamarin.Forms/Samples/DataGrid_GettingStartedForms.zip here.so its just sample from your server..sttill its not running

Comment: Which version of Xamarin Nuget-Package you are installed currently

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122511/discussion-between-neelam-prajapati-and-divakar).